# How to connect wires from Orange Pi to DIP8 board without a numbered layout?

Tags: layout, dip, soic

I read the documentation, it doesn't tell how to do it.

I have an EEPROM chip containing the BIOS on my laptop's motherboard - an MX25L06E if you need the name. I have an Orange Pi Lite board, and I have a SOIC 8-pin clip like the one in [this video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=2Y06x1f22B0&t=180).  This clip is supposed to connect my board and the EEPROM storage.

The only difference between mine and the one in the video is mine doesn't have the numbered layout on the connection board (I called it DIP8 board in my title,) or whatever it is called properly, anyway you can look at it in the video at this exact timecode.

Here is the picture of my connection board:

[image: DIP-8 Connector Board]

I know the layout of my EEPROM chip, that is how every pin on it makes a pair with the one exact pin on the Orange Pi. What I do not know is how I should connect the wires from the Orange Pi to the connection board, so I pair them in the right order.

Take a look at this to get what I mean:

[image: My Setup]

I don't know how I am supposed to connect the right thing to the left thing. But I could figure it out if the left thing had numbers on it. I presume I can't connect wires in any ordering that I can come up with.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to embed the images directly in the post instead of merely linking to them.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect it to be a 1:1 wiring from pin 1..8 of the SOIC clip to pin 1..8 of the simulated DIP-8, so that  you can plug the small board into the ZIF socket of a dedicated programmer. Viewed from the 'top' (pins down), of course. There may be pin 1 markings on the clip and on the board (but check anyway). Pins are numbered counter-clockwise from the lower left pin 1 dot on DIP packages.

You can check with a multimeter on continuity scale. It's important to get the orientation correct or  you could damage something.